# How to use an if-statement in SalesForce E-Mail Template

Tags: salesforce, email-templates

I'm trying to add a if-Statement to my E-Mailtemplate (Type: HTML). I used the following code:

```
{!if(Lead.LastName="", "1", "2")}
```

My Output is just nothing :/

Does anyone know how to do it right?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Got it work now. I just changed the Formating a bit, and now it works. Very strange...

Comment: I have the same issue. What do you mean with "Formating"? Where do I find it?

Comment: Please show what you changed to help others who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the more complex logic like conditionally rendering data is not available in straightforward emails. `IF`, `BLANKVALUE` etc functions don't work, instead there's something similar to `Dear {!Lead.LastName, 'Sir or Madam'}` that's supposed to be fallback scenario if the field was empty.

If you're not too afraid - make a visualforce email template instead?

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Hello StackOverflow" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Lead">
    <messaging:HtmlEmailBody >
        <p>Related To: {!relatedTo.Name}, {!relatedTo.LeadSource}</p>
        <p>Recipient: {!recipient.Username}</p>

        <p>{!IF(ISBLANK(relatedTo.LeadSource), '1', '2')}</p>
    </messaging:HtmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use following Format, then it should work:

```
{!IF(Lead.LastName='','1','2')}
```